# Iterate through each letter in the string with even index as uppercase and odd index as lowercase

Tags: python, python-3.x

My homework assignment requires me to iterate through each letter in the string with even index as uppercase and odd index as lowercase. It should leave any punctuation marks or numerals unchanged, and it should change the case of every letter at an even index. That means if the letter is initially uppercase, it should be should be converted to lower case.

For example: mock("Abcd. Efgh.. Ijkl!") would return "abCd. efGh.. IJkL!". The even-index letters (A, C, E, g, j, l) changed case, all other characters were unchanged.

I tried to swapcase it and tries to split them and rejoin the string back. But i couldn't get it work.

```py
def mock(word):
    index = 0
    result = ''
    swap = word.swapcase()

    for letter in swap:
        if index % 2 == 0:
            result += letter.upper()
        else:
            result += letter.lower()
        index += 1
    return result
```

We tested your code with a_str = "Abcd. Efgh.. Ijkl!". We expected mock to return the str "abCd. efGh.. IJkL!". However, it returned the str "aBcD. eFgH.. IjKl!".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code currently makes it so letters with odd indexes would become lowercased and letters with even indexes would become uppercased.
If you only want letters on the even indexes to change from lowercase to uppercase or from uppercase to lowercase, you should use the following method:

```
def mock(word):
index = 0
result = ''
for letter in word:
    if index % 2 == 0:
        if letter.isupper():
            result += letter.lower()
        else:
            result += letter.upper()
    else:
        result += letter
    index += 1
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You increment the index after every character rather than every letter. This includes characters like punctuation, empty spaces, numbers.

You need to add a conditional statement before you increment the index using the isalpha() function:

```
If letter.isalpha()
  Index += 1
```

Also, you need to add another conditional statement to check if the even letters are already uppercase so that you switch their case.